# php-mbstring install - version conflict (Cent OS)

Tags: centos, php

I am running CentOS 6.3 and I need to install mb-string for PHP.  When I attempt to do this I get the following:

```
[root@pixelark popups]# yum install php-mbstring
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * Webmin: download.webmin.com
 * base: centos.mirrors.hoobly.com
 * epel: epel.mirror.freedomvoice.com
 * extras: mirrors.versaweb.com
 * updates: mirrors.usc.edu
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.3-23.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4 for package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
       Installed: php-common-5.3.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.15-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have done a

```
yum update
```

and it is still showing.  I have tried updating php in a similar fashion and it says that there are no updates.  I do not know what direction I should be going.  Should I be trying the two suggestions on the bottom

```
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I dont want to break anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using RPM's from Remi Collet's repository.

Do exactly one of the following:

1. Uninstall remi's rpm's (can be listed with `rpm -qa|grep remi`) and install packages with same name (I recommend this, [because of this](https://serverfault.com/questions/530513/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib64-php-modules-gd-so-undef))
2. Install php-mbstring from remi's repo (`yum install php-mbstring --enablerepo=remi` should work by default)

Comment: Will this effect any data when I remove?  For example I have this package installed: 'mysql-server-5.5.27-1.el6.remi.x86_64'.  If I remove the package, will it remove the MySQL database data?

Comment: no, it wont, but service will be interrupted. you can leave mysql packages as they are, remove only php-related packages. i've never faced any problems with mysql from remi, but php is really problematic.

Comment: I ignored the mysql packages and I followed the instructions above.  Worked great.  Thank you.  For verbose clarity, I used 'yum remove' to uninstall and 'yum install' to install the new packages.

Comment: you're welcome, nice to hear that

Comment: For the record: In five years I have never seen a problem with remi's PHP packages that wasn't a problem with the code itself (rather than the packaging). Rather, remi's packages are very high quality - and he also packages PHP for RHEL!

Answer (score 0):

You installed PHP from the remi repository, but you disabled the repository. So yum can't install additional packages from it.

To resolve the problem, re-enable the remi repository.

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi
```