# Dependency problems updating Centos 6.4, 64 bit

Tags: centos6

I'm having dependency issues while trying to update Centos 6.4 ,64 bit here is the output when I run yum update:

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * epel: ftp.nluug.nl
 * extras: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * rpmforge: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * updates: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
1268 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bash.x86_64 0:4.1.2-14.el6 will be updated
---> Package bash.x86_64 0:4.1.2-15.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.4 will be updated
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 will be an update
---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.4 will be updated
---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 will be an update
---> Package busybox.x86_64 1:1.15.1-15.el6 will be updated
---> Package busybox.x86_64 1:1.15.1-16.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package clusterlib.x86_64 0:3.0.12.1-49.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package clusterlib.x86_64 0:3.0.12.1-49.el6_4.2 will be an update
---> Package cman.x86_64 0:3.0.12.1-49.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package cman.x86_64 0:3.0.12.1-49.el6_4.2 will be an update
---> Package cpuspeed.x86_64 1:1.5-19.el6 will be updated
---> Package cpuspeed.x86_64 1:1.5-20.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package crash-gcore-command.x86_64 0:1.0-3.el6 will be updated
---> Package crash-gcore-command.x86_64 0:1.0-4.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package cups.x86_64 1:1.4.2-50.el6_4.4 will be updated
---> Package cups.x86_64 1:1.4.2-50.el6_4.5 will be an update
---> Package cups-libs.x86_64 1:1.4.2-50.el6_4.4 will be updated
---> Package cups-libs.x86_64 1:1.4.2-50.el6_4.5 will be an update
---> Package firefox.x86_64 0:17.0.6-1.el6.centos will be updated
---> Package firefox.x86_64 0:17.0.8-1.el6.centos will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: xulrunner >= 17.0.8 for package: firefox-17.0.8-1.el6.centos.x86_64
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.2 will be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.4 will be an update
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.2 will be updated
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.4 will be an update
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.2 will be updated
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.4 will be an update
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.2 will be updated
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.4 will be an update
---> Package gnome-screensaver.x86_64 0:2.28.3-24.el6 will be updated
---> Package gnome-screensaver.x86_64 0:2.28.3-24.el6_4.1 will be an update
---> Package gstreamer-plugins-bad.x86_64 0:0.10.19-9.el6 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: libxvidcore.so.4()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libvdpau.so.1()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libschroedinger-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmusicbrainz.so.4()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmplex2-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmodplug.so.1()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmms.so.0()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmjpegutils-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liblrdf.so.2()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libkate.so.1()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfaad.so.2()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfaac.so.0()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdvdnav.so.4()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdirac_encoder.so.0()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdirac_decoder.so.0()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdca.so.0()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdc1394.so.22()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcdaudio.so.1()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libass.so.4()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libamrwb.so.3()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
---> Package gstreamer-plugins-bad-free.x86_64 0:0.10.19-2.el6 will be obsoleted
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-28.el6.centos will be updated
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-29.el6.centos will be an update
---> Package httpd-manual.noarch 0:2.2.15-28.el6.centos will be updated
---> Package httpd-manual.noarch 0:2.2.15-29.el6.centos will be an update
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.15-28.el6.centos will be updated
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.15-29.el6.centos will be an update
---> Package initscripts.x86_64 0:9.03.38-1.el6.centos.1 will be updated
---> Package initscripts.x86_64 0:9.03.38-1.el6.centos.2 will be an update
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-358.18.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package kernel-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-358.18.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-358.11.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-358.18.1.el6 will be an update
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-358.11.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-358.18.1.el6 will be an update
---> Package kpartx.x86_64 0:0.4.9-64.el6 will be updated
---> Package kpartx.x86_64 0:0.4.9-64.el6_4.2 will be an update
---> Package libtevent.x86_64 0:0.9.17-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package libtevent.x86_64 0:0.9.18-1.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package mod_ssl.x86_64 1:2.2.15-28.el6.centos will be updated
---> Package mod_ssl.x86_64 1:2.2.15-29.el6.centos will be an update
---> Package neon.x86_64 0:0.29.3-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package neon.x86_64 0:0.29.3-3.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package net-snmp.x86_64 1:5.5-44.el6_4.2 will be updated
---> Package net-snmp.x86_64 1:5.5-44.el6_4.4 will be an update
---> Package net-snmp-libs.x86_64 1:5.5-44.el6_4.2 will be updated
---> Package net-snmp-libs.x86_64 1:5.5-44.el6_4.4 will be an update
---> Package net-snmp-utils.x86_64 1:5.5-44.el6_4.2 will be updated
---> Package net-snmp-utils.x86_64 1:5.5-44.el6_4.4 will be an update
---> Package nspr.x86_64 0:4.9.2-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package nspr.x86_64 0:4.9.5-2.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package nss.x86_64 0:3.14.0.0-12.el6 will be updated
---> Package nss.x86_64 0:3.14.3-4.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package nss-softokn.x86_64 0:3.12.9-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package nss-softokn.x86_64 0:3.14.3-3.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 0:3.12.9-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 0:3.14.3-3.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.14.0.0-12.el6 will be updated
---> Package nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.14.3-4.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.14.0.0-12.el6 will be updated
---> Package nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.14.3-4.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package nss-util.x86_64 0:3.14.0.0-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package nss-util.x86_64 0:3.14.3-3.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package openswan.x86_64 0:2.6.32-20.el6_4 will be updated
---> Package openswan.x86_64 0:2.6.32-21.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package perf.x86_64 0:2.6.32-358.11.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package perf.x86_64 0:2.6.32-358.18.1.el6 will be an update
---> Package php-pecl-mongo.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6.remi.1 will be updated
---> Package php-pecl-mongo.x86_64 0:1.4.2-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package prelink.x86_64 0:0.4.6-3.el6 will be updated
---> Package prelink.x86_64 0:0.4.6-3.1.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package sos.noarch 0:2.2-38.el6.centos will be updated
---> Package sos.noarch 0:2.2-38.el6.centos.2 will be an update
---> Package xorg-x11-drv-mga.x86_64 0:1.6.1-7.el6 will be updated
---> Package xorg-x11-drv-mga.x86_64 0:1.6.1-8.el6_4 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package firefox.x86_64 0:17.0.8-1.el6.centos will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: xulrunner >= 17.0.8 for package: firefox-17.0.8-1.el6.centos.x86_64
---> Package gstreamer-plugins-bad.x86_64 0:0.10.19-9.el6 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: libmodplug.so.1()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
---> Package libamrwb.x86_64 0:7.0.0.4-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libass.x86_64 0:0.9.11-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libenca.so.0()(64bit) for package: libass-0.9.11-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package libcdaudio.x86_64 0:0.99.12p2-11.el6 will be installed
---> Package libdc1394.x86_64 0:2.1.2-3.4.el6 will be installed
---> Package libdca0.x86_64 0:0.0.5-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package libdirac.x86_64 0:1.0.2-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package libdvdnav.x86_64 0:4.1.4-0.1.svn1184.el6 will be installed
---> Package libfaac.x86_64 0:1.28-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libfaad2.x86_64 1:2.7-18.el6 will be installed
---> Package libkate.x86_64 0:0.3.7-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package liblrdf.x86_64 0:0.5.0-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ladspa for package: liblrdf-0.5.0-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libraptor2.so.0()(64bit) for package: liblrdf-0.5.0-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package libmms.x86_64 0:0.6.2-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package libmusicbrainz.x86_64 0:2.1.5-11.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libschroedinger.x86_64 0:1.0.10-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libvdpau1.x86_64 0:0.4.1-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package libxvidcore.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package mjpegtools.x86_64 1:2.0.0-22.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libquicktime.so.0()(64bit) for package: 1:mjpegtools-2.0.0-22.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-mongo.x86_64 0:1.4.2-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package firefox.x86_64 0:17.0.8-1.el6.centos will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: xulrunner >= 17.0.8 for package: firefox-17.0.8-1.el6.centos.x86_64
---> Package gstreamer-plugins-bad.x86_64 0:0.10.19-9.el6 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: libmodplug.so.1()(64bit) for package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64
---> Package ladspa.x86_64 0:1.13-6.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libenca.x86_64 0:1.13-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libquicktime0.x86_64 0:1.2.4-31.el6 will be installed
---> Package libraptor2.x86_64 0:2.0.7-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-mongo.x86_64 0:1.4.2-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.5.0-0.33.RC2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
Error: Package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-9.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libmodplug.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.5.0-0.33.RC2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
Error: Package: firefox-17.0.8-1.el6.centos.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: xulrunner >= 17.0.8
           Installed: xulrunner-17.0.6-2.el6.centos.x86_64 (@updates)
               xulrunner = 17.0.6-2.el6.centos
           Available: xulrunner-1.9.2.4-0.10.el6.x86_64 (atrpms-stable)
               xulrunner = 1.9.2.4-0.10.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I'm fairly new to Centos but I've been using GNU/Linux, Ubuntu for two years.
Thanks for looking.

Comment: How many different repositories are you using? Also, this doesn't look like a server.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra repo or two. Can you run `yum repolist` ?

Comment: thanks, its a minimum install of Centos ,but i hope to upgrade to a full server eventually, here's the output for repolist:

Answer (score 1):

You've got PHP 5.5 installed from Remi Collet's repo. PHP modules require PHP of same version, because there is binding on binary level.

php-pecl-mongo package from update requires version 5.3, which is available from other/original repos, and you've got 5.5.

try

```
yum update --enablerepo=remi
```

If this doesn't work, install required remi-release package: http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en

If this doesn't help, then you can either ignore update with `--skip-broken` or search for mongo module package from other sources.

Comment: thanks GioMac, it doesnt work but i'm looking intothe leads you gave, will get back  with more info

Comment: you need module for 5.5. According to experience, Remi's 5.5 PHP is problematic, if PHP 5.3 is ok for you - uninstall remi packages and install php 5.3 packages from original repos. Also, remove rpmforge.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/530513/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib64-php-modules-gd-so-undef/530523#530523